# Compose Custom Progress Animation With Pause/Resume

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a progress bar with pause and play, like this.

[image]

How can I got this output with compose ?

I tried a lot of animations but couldn't handle with the start/stop operations. What is the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is this one I think:

```
val progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
val animatedProgress by animateFloatAsState(targetValue = progress,
    animationSpec = tween(
        durationMillis = 1000,        
        easing = LinearEasing
    ))
val paused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

LaunchedEffect(paused) {
    if (!paused) while (progress < 1f) {
        progress += 0.1f //or another step
        delay(1000)  //or another delay
    }
}
```

Here it is not even necessary to use animation, you can directly apply the `progress` value as a component's size fraction.

animatedProgress animates to target value, which is "pausable" in this solution. So when the target value doesn't change, the animation stops

Comment: If I set delay 1 or 10 for smooth filling, progress bar not fill in my expected time. For example, `delay(1000)` and `progress += 1000/myExpectedFilledTime` it's okey but not smooth. `delay(1)` and `progress += 1/myExpectedFilledTime` it's smooth but filled in much more than expected time.

Comment: Use `animatedProgress` then and provide `animationSpec(durationMillis = <same as delay>, easing = LinearEasing)` to `animateFloatAsState`. See updated answer.

Comment: `animatedProgress` animates to target value, which is "pausable" in my solution. So when the target value doesn't change, the animation stops.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @bylazy. Can u change the durationMillis same as delay and final sentence in your answer ?